# QAxWidget don’t display

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qtgui, qaxwidget

I used QWidget show as a dialog. And put QAxWidget as a subwidget.
But if I set the parent widget transparent, the QAxWidget will not display.

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
......;

QAxWidget* axieBrowser= new QAxWidget(widget);
axieBrowser->setControl(QString::fromUtf8("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}"));
axieBrowser->dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", "www.google.com");
```

I try if you use other widget, that will display, only QAxWidget don’t display! How could I fi
xed that?

Comment: Is it the same with any other widget, like a QLabel within the outter QWidget?

Comment: This may be a limitation of ActiveX widgets - but just to be completely sure, do you need Internet Explorer or ActiveX specifically? If you just need to display vendor-neutral webpages, the QtWebkit library does a good job.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I use other widget like label, which will display. @ John Chadwick Yes, I have to use Internet Explorer , can't use QWebView instead.

Comment: Does it display if put inside some layout management? If I understand correctly it does display but only if you ommit the setAttribute() part, correct?

Comment: Not display. The attribute WA_TranslucentBackground can't be set.

Comment: Could you tell me which operating system you run on and which display style you have in use?

Comment: Windows XP. I use widget display as a dialog and it contains a QAxWidget. Now I found a way can let is display which is change the widget's geometry. The funciton is in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

@Dariusz Scharsig I use this function to force the QWidget fresh because repaint() is no effect.

```
void CMyDialog::changeRectToFresh()
{
    this->showNorMal();
    QRect rect = this->geometry();
    this->setGeometry(rect.adjusted(-1,-1,1,1);
    //recover
    this->setCeometry(rect);
}
```